# In managed .NET CSOM, why do we have to load list to get items when we are already loading the web?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

We are using managed .NET CSOM.

We are loading the web.

But when we try to fetch list names using web.lists, we get error.

To resolve we have to load web.lists.

Why do we have to load list to get items when we are already loading the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSOM attempts to load as little information as possible unless you explicitly ask for it. In this case, if I were only interested in the web's ID or Title, loading all of the lists would take alot of extra time and provide no benefit, especially if there were thousands of them.

There will be differing opinions on what the 'minimum' amount of info is for each ClientContextObject load, but making it more granular allows for greater control.

Answer (score 1):

The client object model does not retrieve collection properties for any object unless you specifically request them (by calling Load or LoadQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the technical reason, but I think it's because the list names are properties of the list object, not the web.  You can try this, if you want to use one load statement:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext( url );
ctx.Load( ctx.Web, web => web.Lists.Include( list => list.Title ) );
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```